# Dynamic String Manipulation VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string from a Sharepoint list that returns data like this:

```
"Doe, John;#44" or "Doe, Jane;#150".
```

I need to be able to remove the semicolon and any characters after that. Since they can be 4, 5 or even 6 characters I can't use the right function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InStr` to locate the semicolon and the `Left` to extract the part to the left of it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = "Doe, John;#44"
    i = InStr(1, s, ";")
    s = Left(s, i - 1)
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

This prints `Doe, John`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula `REPLACE(LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1),1,1,)`, assuming data is in cell A1.